# How to simulate fixed plane using SimScape Multibody Contact Forces Library?

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

I am trying to simulate the contact forces between a fixed plane and a sphere in MATLAB Simulink using the Multibody Contact Forces Library https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47417-simscape-multibody-contact-forces-library as shown in this MATLAB webinar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZIG0HlBHC4 at 9:58. However, when I recreate the model and run the simulation myself, I get the following error.

```
External Force and Torque External_Force_and_Torque_PlaB has its follower port rigidly connected to the world frame; it has no effect. You can configure this diagnostic in the Simscape Multibody Configuration Parameters dialog.
```

I've tried adding another constraint/joint between the World Frame and the planar solid to resolve the issue, but I keep getting the same error? How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. Have a look here: https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/378561-rigidly-connected-port-error-with-simscape-multibody-contact-forces-library

This error is due to a default setting with new Simulink models, which is incompatible with the Contact Forces Library.

To resolve this:

1. Go to **Simulation > Model Configuration Parameters**
2. In the **Simscape Multibody > Diagnostics** pane, change the "Rigidly constrained block" diagnostic to "warning" or "none"

[image: Simscape Multibody > Diagnostics]